# Can't turn of auto create function in embedded ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I would like to use ActiveMQ in my Spring Boot application. During debugging I have found out following error:

```
org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ (localhost, null)javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost`
```

Seems like broker is created upon creation of the first connection, according to ActiveMQ's documentation. Is is possible to turn off auto-creation by setting the `create` property on the VM Transport to `false`, e.g.:

```java
ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?create=false");
```

When I tried this solution I got following error:

```
DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'test' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=364, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Broker named 'localhost' does not exist.
```

Now I think the broker is not creating at all or this process is pending. Did anyone have a similar issue? If so how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ's [vm transport](http://activemq.apache.org/vm-transport-reference) optionally creates a broker, or connects to a running broker.

Sounds like you are missing a step in your application boot-up plan. Either you need:

1. A component to startup the broker
2. Designate one of the connection factories to start the broker using the vm transport:

Designated broker startup connection factory:

```
vm://localhost?create=true
```

All other connection factories:

```
vm://localhost?create=false
```